# Can't run my docker image with a mounted volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I created a Volume using Docker Desktop, called Downloads. I bind it successfully with a ftp, i can add/remove files and i can see it in the Data tab about the downloads volume.

I have a home made api that i want it to access the downloads volume but when i run it, the container just displays the node version.

```
v17.9.1
```

The dockerfile :

```
FROM node:17

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --quiet
COPY . .
VOLUME downloads /downloads
CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```

The build command :

```
docker build . -t myapi/myapidev
```

The command :

```
docker run -p 3001:3001 --name API -d myapi/myapidev -v downloads:/downloads
```

What do i do wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
docker run -p 3001:3001 --name API -d -v downloads:/downloads myapi/myapidev
```

Name of the image must be at the end of command.

Comment: It's working. I wouldn't have find it myself, no error, nothing. Thank's a lot. I'll approve this answer in 3 minuts.